# how to detect a browser supports requestFullscreen

Tags: jquery, fullscreen

How can I detect a browser supports `requestFullscreen` or not?

I have these codes below to make chrome, safari, firefox, and opera (not entirely working) to make a document fullscreen, but I want to detect the browser supports `requestFullscreen` or not. What should I do?

```
 $('.button-fullscreen').click(function(){ 

    var docElm = document.documentElement;

    // W3C Proposal
    if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
        docElm.requestFullscreen();
    }

    // mozilla proposal
    else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();          
    }

    // Webkit (works in Safari and Chrome Canary)
    else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen(); 
    }

    return false;
});

$('.button-sound').click(function(){               

    // W3C Proposal
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    }

    // mozilla proposal
    else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    }

    // Webkit (works in Safari and Chrome Canary)
    else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modernizr framework to avoid testing for n vendor prefixes...

```
Modernizr.prefixed('requestFullscreen', document.documentElement)
```

Comment: Modernizr currently relies on https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js if you want to cut out the middleman

Answer (score 3):

When you put `if (docElm.requestFullscreen)`, you are detecting if the browser supports that method because it will return true if `requestFullscreen` is defined on the `docElm`object.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the ideas from screenful this seems to work

```
  const canFullscreen = (function() {
    for (const key of [
        'exitFullscreen',
        'webkitExitFullscreen',
        'webkitCancelFullScreen',
        'mozCancelFullScreen',
        'msExitFullscreen',
      ]) {
      if (key in document) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }());


  if (canFullscreen) {
    // supported
  } else {
    // not-supported
  }
```

note: for my purposes I didn't need a library to do fullscreen. I just needed code to detect if it's possible as I'm using some other library that goes can go fullscreen but I needed to know whether or not to display the an option to go fullscreen to then call into that library. In other words, if canFullscreen show button, else don't.

Comment: what @gman mentioned above worked for me with a tweak. Just check for 'exitFullscreen', because others can be included in the document even though it is not supported. I've tested it on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Safari. With the above tweak only on Safari canFullScreen is set to false --where it is not supported. All other browsers which sets it to true supports  fullscreen too.