# Replace Qualtrics Text entry with NULL

Tags: javascript, text, qualtrics

I want to prevent Qualtrics from capturing a text field where respondents are asked to enter a user name and password. Is there any way to simply replace the text they enter with "NULL" or something similar?

Thanks!

EDIT: The only code I've tried so far is one that can find and replace all characters (via RegEx), but I'm pretty sure I'm using regex wrong.

```
var inputs = $(this.questionContainer).select('input');
inputs.each(function(el) {if (el.value == '.') el.value='';});
```

EDIT: (re: T. Gibbons) Apologies, let me clarify.... basically I want to text that is submitted to Qualtrics to be empty, I would like the change to be made when they hit 'next.' I am trying to simulate people logging into a social media platform, but I don't want to capture their login info for privacy reasons... therefore I'm looking for a way convert their real login information into something meaningless. Thanks for any guidance you might be able to provide!

Comment: You should add to your question the code that you tried to run to achieve what you're looking for, if you've already done so.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any regex. All it does is change inputs with a value of '.' to blank on page load, so it doesn't appear to be a serious attempt. When do you want to change the value? (when they move off the field, when they click Next, etc.).  And, why are you asking questions that you don't want to know the answer to?  Please answer by editing your original post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the NextButton and add a fake NextButton.  Then put an event listener on the fake NextButton to erase the values then click the real NextButton. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228156/automatically-resize-to-full-screen-when-clicking-next-button/33260645#33260645).